# Setup Drupal select list field with CCK to pull allowed values list with PHP

Tags: php, drupal, cck, populate, selectlist

In a content type called "School", I am trying to build my select list called League based off of the title of a content type called "League Name".

The idea is that if the owner of the site wanted to add a new League in this select list, they would add a new page to the "League Name" content type and it would repopulate the select list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can* do it by using PHP to set the allowed values of the select list, but I would just use a node reference field, choosing the select list widget and in the settings choose the league content type.  The node reference field will do the work for you by populating the select list with all League nodes.

For more information on node references, take a look at the [CCK Nodereference Screencast](http://geoffhankerson.com/drupal/cck-nodereference-screencast.html)

Comment: Laxman13, 

As I was looking into implementing your solution I found out about taxonomy vocabulary lists. I am now using that in conjunction with a select list term reference field. This eliminated coding all together and allows for the select list to be populated based on the vocabulary list.

Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a vocabulary list in conjunction with a select list term reference field. This eliminated coding all together and allows for the select list to be populated based on the vocabulary list.